# No data inserted into mssql database using php

Tags: php, sql, sql-server

I would like to insert data from a form using php into mssql 2012.

[image]

The above picture shows I installed drivers for php to work with mssql and after testing the connection it was success.

Following is the script written to do the insertion:

```
$serverName = "SUPERMAN";

$connectionInfo = array('Database'=>'xikwambene', "UID"=>"develop", "PWD"=>"develop");
$conn = sqlsrv_connect($serverName, $connectionInfo);

if($conn) {
    echo "Connection established.<br />";
}else {
    echo "Connection could not be established.<br />";
    die(print_r(sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}


if(empty($_POST) === false && empty($errors)=== true)
        {

            $id = $_POST['id'];
            $name = $_POST['name'];

            $query = "INSERT INTO dbo.test (id,name)
                        VALUES  ('$id','$name')GO";

            $result = sqlsrv_prepare($conn,$query)or die('Error querying MSSQL database');
            sqlsrv_execute($result);





            //redirect
            header('Location: Address_insert.php');
            exit();                                 
        }


?>
```

Now the problem is nothing gets inserted into the database, and it successfully redirects to

Address_insert.php

Please Assist. its my first day working with php and mssql

Comment: You don't check for errors.

Comment: The connection is established?

Comment: even when I add `error_reporting(E_ALL);` to the script I still don't get any errors

Comment: Yes! connection was successfully established

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if(empty($_POST) === false && empty($errors)=== true)
        {

            $id = $_POST['id'];
            $name = $_POST['name'];
            print_r($_POST);



            $query = "INSERT INTO dbo.test (id,name)
                        VALUES  (?,?)";

                $params = array($id, $name);        
            $stmt = sqlsrv_query( $conn, $query, $params);

            if( $stmt === false ) {
         die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
                }
```

The answer is based on information from: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sqlsrv-query.php

Answer (score 0):

After this code:

```
 $id = $_POST['id'];
 $name = $_POST['name'];
```

add this :

```
$id = $_POST['id'];
$name = $_POST['name'];
print_r($_POST)
```

to see if the script receive the php variables sent thru $_POST and comment :

```
//header('Location: Address_insert.php'); so you can see the print.
```

This method for me always give results.

Best regards!

Comment: When add print_r. I get the following output : **Array ( [id] => 1 [name] => motho ) **

Comment: After try to execute this query: "INSERT INTO dbo.test (id,name)
                        VALUES  ('1','motho ')GO " direclty to database.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean. are you saying I must type the script into my sql studio to see if the query works ?

Answer (score 0):

```
    $query = "INSERT INTO dbo.test (id,name)
                VALUES  ('$id','$name')GO";


   $result = sqlsrv_prepare($conn,$query)or die('Error querying MSSQL database');
```

Here, `$query` is *not* compatible for a prepared statement. You don't assign parameters in queries in prepared statements, you use place holders like `?`. If you wish to use prepared statements, you are doing it in a wrong way. If you wish to use regular queries, you would want to remove the `sqlsrv_prepare ( )` line of code.

Comment: what should I replace the prepare statement with ?